# XNA program limited to 640x480 box on fullscreen

Tags: xna, fullscreen, monogame

I'm in Linux, trying to learn XNA (MonoGame).

I have a basic test application, and I'm trying to make it work on fullscreen, like it should. However, the application itself becomes limited to a small 640x480px box in the lower left corner of the screen. The origin for this box is in the upper-left corner.

[Here's a useful graphic to show what's going on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55WeT.jpg) (I made this graphic using my application itself, so it's as accurate as it gets)

Smallest runnable code:

```
public class Game : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    public Game()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1366;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 768;
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize ();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    { }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw (GameTime gameTime)
    {
        graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear (Color.CornflowerBlue);            
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Anyone got any insight to share on this?

Comment: Just to be clear, is the `Clear` clearing the whole screen or just the "usable region"? (Either way, this sounds like a bug in MonoGame).

Comment: This could very well be a bug in MonoGame, or after a quick look at the source code it may even be in OpenTK. Have you tried other screen resolutions? 1024x768 or 1280x720 perhaps? https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/blob/develop/MonoGame.Framework/Desktop/OpenTKGamePlatform.cs

Comment: @AndrewRussell, Clear is clearing the whole screen, which is weird.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be a bug with MonoGame. Since there isn't anything to do besides wait, I guess my problem is "fixed".

Comment: Is there a bug/issue against this? Please link to that if you found one or raise one if not. That will help people who might see similar behavior figure out the status of this issue at a later date. Thanks!